# Missing column name during ActiveAdmin query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2, using a SQL Server 2008 database through the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem.  I'm working with a legacy database, so this was not voluntary.

I'm running into an odd problem with ActiveAdmin.  I've not used ActiveAdmin before, and added it after watching a Railscast.  Followed the standard installation instructions, and I'm able to log into the admin console.

When I add a model:

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Payment
```

The model (in plural) is now visible on the ActiveAdmin dashboard.  However, when I click on the link, I get the following error:

```
TinyTds::Error: No column name was specified for column 2 of '__rnt'.: EXEC 
sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [__rnt].* FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER
BY [Payments].[UPaymentID] ASC) AS [__rn], 1 FROM [Payments] ) AS [__rnt] 
WHERE [__rnt].[__rn] > (0) ORDER BY [__rnt].[__rn] ASC'
```

Now, this query returns the same error if I run it directly on the SQL Server database - it doesn't like the unnamed column of "1".

Started digging to see what the issue was.  The obvious places to look would be in the transitions between activeadmin and activerecord, and then activerecord and the SQL Server adapter.  Here's the stack trace for the first intersection:

```
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:197:in `exists?'  
activeadmin (0.4.2) lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb:41:in `items_in_collection?'  
activeadmin (0.4.2) lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb:20:in `main_content'
```

It looks like items_in_collection? is calling exists? on a collection that has had order filters removed.  At this point, we're handing off to ActiveRecord.  If we look at the transition from ActiveRecord to the SQL Server adapter, it looks as if the SELECT statement has already been formed:

```
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:348:in `do_exec_query'
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:24:in `exec_query'
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:297:in `select'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `block in select_all'
```

I'm totally confused as to why the SQL would be generated the way that it is.  There are a couple of candidate problem areas:

1. I'm working on a legacy database with an odd schema.  I'm having to set table names and primary key names within my models.  I don't *think* this is the issue, since the query that is coming out seems to use the appropriate primary key and table names.
2. Problems with the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem.  However, I pulled the source code, and it sure doesn't look like there is anything there that would be assembling this query in that way.

Has anyone run into anything similar to this?  It may be that I'll just need to debug my way through the whole stack to see what's going on.  Figured it would be worth checking here first though.

Edit:  I'm now fairly sure this is a bug in activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.  Will post resolution here once I have it.

Edit2:  Can reproduce the error without ActiveAdmin at all.  This is related to the way that the sql server adapter deals with offset queries.  Calling

```
MyModel.offset(1).exists?
```

produces the same error.  I have an ugly patch to the adapter which passes all the unit tests, but I'm going to try to find a more elegant solution before making a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly the answer, but I patched my local code and your query works for me now.

First, the github issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1623

and then the pull request for arkadiyk's fix:

https://github.com/arkadiyk/rails/commit/7e2ddddb303d17adc825ebb691097a93902fa539

The basic problem is finder_methods.rb, which has the existing code around line 187 or 188:

```
relation = relation.except(:select).select("1").limit(1)
```

MSSQL barfs on the unnamed column this generates, so the following code fixes it:

```
relation = relation.except(:select).select("1 as o").limit(1)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I have mixed feelings about where the right place to fix this would be.  Clearly, rails can make our lives easier by aliasing a column in which 1 is selected, but I'd like to think that it shouldn't have to, as this is more of an issue that is specific to the database.  I have a patch on activerecord-sqlserver-adapter that accomplishes the same thing, but does so in a much uglier way (basically visit the node during the select processing, and append an alias column if the node is just "1").  I'll post an answer as well with a link back to my pull request.

Comment: Agreed.  I can also see a general adapter feature that manufactures temp column names and then cleans them up from the query and the result set at the very end of the processing.  That would permit the adapter to manage which columns it introduced, as well as possibly to allow the user to specify a different generator for column names.    Just an idea.  I haven't looked closely enough at the code to see what makes best sense.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two alternatives to fixing this:  fix it in rails, or fix it in activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.

The link that Raels has provided is probably the right way to fix this, however, the pull request has not been accepted into rails.  I'm concerned about using a patched version of rails, as this will force me to either stick with my patched version, or continue to patch as rails evolves.

Al alternative is to fix this in activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.  I've submitted a pull request here:

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/pull/171

It's possible that the maintainer of active-sqlserver-adapter will come up with a more elegant fix.  If he does, I'll update this answer.